# Merge a deleted question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, merged-questions

The question [Most shameful/awesome language hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962747/most-shameful-awesome-language-hack) closed as duplicate of
the [What programming hack from your past are you most ashamed of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155968/what-programming-hack-from-your-past-are-you-most-ashamed-of)

A couple of hours ago it got deleted, to my surprise.
High rep users cannot merge (or vote to merge) questions but they can vote to delete them.
In this case, I believe there was no reason for deletion.

I wanted to flag the question and notify a moderator, but deleted questions can't be flagged.
Can a moderator please merge it to the older question?

Thanks in advance.

<sub>PS: 10K+ rep users can vote to undelete it</sub>

Comment: The question should be merged with its parent question. It is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really ought to add some form protection for these highly voted questions so they can't be deleted quite so easily.

Deletion was really intended for the "worst of the worst", or truly and blatantly off-topic stuff, not this...

edit: we now scale deletion votes required to the # of votes on the entire question and all answers. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071) for more.

Comment: yesterday I didn't notice the "flag" option on the deleted question. Did you change it or am I blind?

Comment: @nick we did add flagging for deleted posts

Answer (score 1):

I call failure of the community moderating system when a duplicate was re-opened.  People have an aversion to closing, but this question should have been closed long before this became an issue.

Looking at the revision history:

Question asked on:

```
asked Jun 7 '09 at 20:29
```

Question Closed 4 hours later:

```
Post Closed as "not a real question" by DOK, karim79, Neil Butterworth, dmckee, 
John Saunders
occurred Jun 8 '09 at 0:17
```

And later Re-opened:

```
Post Reopened by Ayman Hourieh, Nils Pipenbrinck, JaredPar, Kevin, Jeff Atwood♦`
occurred Jun 9 '09 at 0:52
```

The question should be merged with its parent question.

Of course, this calls into question the whole: 'It's closed as the wrong reason so we should re-open it' mentality.

The question was rightly closed, but the wrong reason (due to community voting) took effect. That means even if 2 people saw it was a duplicate, the other three chose a different reason (maybe those three voted before the two that found the duplicate?).

Comment: yes, that's what I proposed. I don't mind that it got closed, but it should be merged instead of get deleted.