# "-4 more vote(s) needed to delete this question"

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909674/why-is-vb-so-popular-closed). When you hover over the `(7)` in the delete button, it says: `-4 more vote(s) needed to delete this question`. It seems that this always assumes that 3 votes are needed to delete the question, which [isn't true anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071).

[image: Screenshot for the lazy]

Comment: Note for clarification: you have to hover over the (7) section of the button, not just the "delete" portion of the button. If you hover over "delete" portion, you get "vote to remove this post".

Comment: After voting to delete it, the message informed me that one more vote was required... But now hovering over the number informs me that -5 votes are needed.

Comment: This reminds me of when we had 18 votes to close a question for migration. Possibly the same issue rearing its head for the new delete vote limits?

Comment: What's with the `(s)`? Has he received a pluralization bug [1 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694) too many?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good eyes! This has been fixed and will be pushed tonight.

Comment: Now it gives a different sort of wrong results. I think it's giving the total votes needed instead of the amount remaining. For example, this question says 3 more votes needed when it already has 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888982/is-writing-a-portable-code-important-closed

Comment: @interjay - a fix for that will be pushed tonight.  Thank you again!

Comment: Got one more for you Jarrod.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237448  Has three, saying it needs three more.

Comment: @JeffMercado that's because it's a more popular question - see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071) where we define how aggregate score affects delete votes needed.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Ah thanks for pointing that out.  I thought it was just a fixed, three votes required.

Comment: Has this problem reappeared? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195031/6-more-votes-are-needed-to-delete-this-post?noredirect=1#comment614191_195031