# How does this question says 4 more votes needed to delete, but total score is only 41?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete, tooltips

[What will happen when I call a member function on a NULL object pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533476/trick-c-interview-question-closed)

Currently there is 3 delete votes and, With [20:1 ratio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), there should be needed only **2 extra votes** + 3 based votes, but it says now **4 more votes** needed to delete when I hover the delete `(n)` link

Following is the scores of each posts on that question currently, first one is on question.

```
[3, 27, 6, 2, 2, 1, -1, -4, -5, -5]
```

If I don't count minus scored answers, total score is 41, and when I count all its only 26 scored.

So, I feel like `4 more votes needed to delete` as bug,

and minus scored answers count in delete vote calculations or no?

---

**Edit**: Question just got deleted with 4 total votes, so **only** the hover text was just wrong, and looks like minus scored answers count towards delete-vote calculation.

---

**Edit2**: Added a screen shot

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1889/287873.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1889/287873.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug introduced after the fix to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51266/4-more-votes-needed-to-delete-this-question). See my comment to Jarrod Dixon's answer on that question: It always reports the total number of votes needed to delete, without subtracting the number of votes already cast.

Edit: This has been fixed - see [Jarrod's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51266/4-more-votes-needed-to-delete-this-question/51366#51366).