# -6 more votes are needed to delete this post

Tags: bug, specific-question, vote-to-delete

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556183/make-c-crash-without-casting

> [image]

Need I say more? :)

Comment: Robert used his magical mod powers and cast the -7th vote :P

Comment: I was able to delete it.  I think we can chalk this up to bugs that were already fixed, but nobody ever got back to cast one more vote to delete it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but it was posted about a full year after that bug was "fixed", meaning whatever it was, it's not fixed.

Comment: I left Jarrod Dixon a comment so he could re-check it.

Comment: Was this really marked as a duplicate of a [meta-tag:status-completed]? Obviously, it's not fixed if it's being reported again.

Comment: Oh no! Now where will I go when I need a list of undefined behaviors?

Comment: @Cole let Jarrod look into it, if not fixed I'll ask to reopen this one.

Comment: @CodyGray [Google](http://google.com/search?q=undefined%20behavior%20example)

Comment: @ColeJohnson I believe that was a rhetorical question. :P

Comment: Ironically, @Cole, the first two Google results are "big list" questions on Stack Overflow. Don't let the Shadowy Wizard get ahold of them, he and his delete button will break the Google!

Comment: @Cody hey, it's Wizardly Shadow around here where everything is gray! ;)