# Recently Deleted Questions - Show total votes required to delete

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, deleted-questions

Given the new [deletion rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), the current display of the [Recently Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) page has become a little less useful.  Showing the vote count used to be an indicator of where a question was in the delete process, `n/3` votes meant `~n*33%` towards deletion...but since that's a variable number now, showing "**4**" under "Most Delete Votes" doesn't really give as much information as it used to.

I think the simplest solution to make this as useful/informative again would be to show the number of total votes needed, as a fraction, e.g. "4 (**7 / 10** Needed)".  The first count would be the same as it is currently, the delete votes in the time range you're looking at. The fraction part would be the total votes (regardless of time), the same count that would be seen on the question page.

One further suggestion to go along with this: under the same "Most Deleted Votes" section, it may make more sense to order this by that fraction/percentage, rather than the votes-so-far count.  While a question may have 6 votes to close, it may require 20, so even though a question has the most votes, it may be the furthest away from actually being deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is viewable on the question page itself, as a tooltip for the current delete votes:

> ... | delete (7) | ...

*Not* the "delete" text, but "(7)".

It would be more useful if it wasn't so hidden, but as someone that watches that section of the 10k tools about once a day, it doesn't seem that big of a deal.

It wouldn't be consistent exactly where you suggest, because that only shows votes in the selected time frame instead of votes so far.  For example, the 2 day range currently shows a question listed at 4 votes, but it actually has 13 so far, with one more required to delete.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I didn't realize this was there, I had only hovered over the "delete" text...that tooltip should be across both elements IMO.

Comment: I cleared up the question a bit, good point on the time range, didn't think of that part since I'm always looking at the 2 day range.