# Deleting your own post or why 7 votes isn't enough

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

I can't delete my own question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963668/most-common-software-development-mistakes-closed

After reading this question

[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

I assume, that it's because the question has more than 2 answers and more than 2 votes and maybe because it is popular question.

So I found this question

[Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)

It's needed 1 vote of deletion for every 20 votes of the question + 3 botes votes. The question has 26 votes at this moment, so I consider we need 5 votes for deletion. At this moment there are 7 votes and it's not enough.

My question's are:

1) How much votes is left?

2) Can I see my own deleted questions?

Thank you.

**P.S.** Maybe I misunderstood something or didn't pay attention to some information in faq. If so just point me the right link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's [1 delete vote for every 20 votes on the question or *any of its answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)... The total number of such votes is currently 159, making the number of delete votes required 7+3=10.

Comment: hmm..how do you get the 159? Is there any way to count it automatically?

Comment: If there is, I don't know about it. Just scrolled and started summing... So yeah, might be off.

Comment: It's definitely 159. And my vote doesn't count in any case, right?

Comment: It should... If it lets you vote. Not sure how that all works at present.

Comment: It says, too many existing answers or/and accepted uptoved/accepted answers

Comment: Ok. Might want to just flag for a moderator's attention then.

Comment: Ok, thanks, flagged it. And what about to be able to see your own deleted question. Is there any possibility?

Comment: @hgulyan: once you have >= 10K reputation points, you'll be able to see it (assuming you kept a link - it won't appear in  your profile). 'Til then, you're best off saving it somewhere else...

Comment: I have it on my computer and after(if) I'll get to 10k, I won't even remember about my question.

Answer (score 0):

***I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.***

["I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid can't do that. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/425505/im_sorry_dave.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/425505/im_sorry_dave.jpg)

Sorry... couldn't resist.