# "0 more vote(s) needed to delete this question"

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I was checking the Delete queue, when I noticed a question that has "0 more vote(s) required to delete this question", as shown below:

[image]

If you click and go into the question, however, it remains undeleted.  Weird.

And yes, as I was typing in this question, I saw a number of duplicate answers, but they're *all* marked Status Complete, and since this is still happening, clearly it's not Status Complete.

- ["0 more votes are needed to undelete this post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215874/0-more-votes-are-needed-to-undelete-this-post)
- ["-4 more vote(s) needed to delete this question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51266/4-more-votes-needed-to-delete-this-question)
- [Negative number of votes needed to undelete an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116017/negative-number-of-votes-needed-to-undelete-an-answer)

Comment: The posts you linked to are about the question page itself, this one here is about the 10k tools, whole different beast.

Comment: @ShadowWizard -- ahh, yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will describe what happened.

The question had 12 upvotes and had answer with 8 upvotes, resulting on total score of 20 which means one extra delete vote is required. ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/152859))

With the above in effect, the question got 3 delete votes, needing 1 more to delete it. Now someone downvoted the question, reducing the total score to 19 and the required votes to 3 or in reverse, 0 more are required as it already got 3.

I don't think it's a good idea to have a single downvote cause instant deletion in such case so it's not a bug, just something that might be displayed better though not sure how.

**Update:** the display of (0) was indeed a bug, [fixed now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256665/447356).

Comment: So 1 MORE close vote is needed to delete the item, so it should say "1 vote needed", not "0 votes needed"

Comment: @Ian nope. It needs 3 votes to delete and already got 3 so, as far as the dry code knows it should put 0 in there. You're right that changing to show "1 more vote is needed" in such a case would be proper workaround.