# Determining how many deletion votes are required

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-delete

The [new deletion rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071) say:

> popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 - a question's popularity is defined by the sum of its score plus all its answers' scores.

Is there an easy way to determine a questions "score", or alternatively to determine how many delete votes would be required to close that question? For example, [1764090](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764090/what-are-the-biggest-potential-time-wasters-in-development-closed) is up to 11 votes; I have no idea if it needs 1 more vote or 30. I could find out by voting to delete, but obviously that's less than ideal

If there is no other way, it might be useful to include that information somewhere; for example, changing the link to say "delete (11/12)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of [14th March, 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/212576):

> A question (or answer) with Votes to Close (or Delete) now shows the number of votes already cast and the number of votes needed to close (or delete) (e.g., (2/5))

For example:

> [image: http://stackoverflow.com/q/632808/1190388]

Answer (score 5):

If you hover `(11)` in `delete (11)`, it will show you 14 more votes needed to delete.

Comment: Ah, of course. Every time I can't find information on SO it turns out to be in a tooltip. Thanks

Comment: On an unrelated note, what did you use to add the timeline link? I assumed it was a greasemonkey script, but I can't find it and remain too lazy to write it myself

Comment: @Michael, yeah it is [a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40617/a-greasemonkey-script-that-adds-timeline-links-to-all-the-questions) greasemonkey script.