# How does delete (10k+) work?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I was browsing the [questions with the most deleted votes](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) in the 10k tools and I still can't seem to understand how delete votes work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166106/calculator-in-c-closed) had 2 votes already, and I agreed so voted to delete, and it was deleted immediately.

but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587748/how-to-convince-my-boss-to-provide-quiet-working-conditions-closed) already has 5 delete votes and hasn't been deleted. (As it happens I think this question actually has good content and should not be deleted)

1. What is the number of votes required to delete?
2. Is there anyway to disagree with delete votes other than commenting?

(Perhaps there should be an official FAQ page on this if there isn't one already that I can't find)

Comment: Its because the question has 52 up votes and 1.3k views, hence more votes to delete it are needed due to its popularity.

Comment: @Tim The 1.3k views is irrelevant. What is more relevant is the score on all of the answers as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 - a question's popularity is defined by the sum of its score plus all its answers' scores.

See [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55095/determining-how-many-deletion-votes-are-required) for an explanation for determining how many delete votes are left to go.

[Full Deletion Rules Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks.