# Create an archive for April fools and the holiday hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013, unicoins, unicorns

I think SE team made a great effort to give us some fun on the fools day. I miss the unicorns, the bacon as a payment, and the holiday hats, and it is a pity that all that stuff will just live in our memories, and eventually get lost for ever and ever.

And here comes the question: Is there any place where we can access to any sort of archive of this stuff (with limited functionality, or just as a image gallery, I don't know) once they are gone?

If not, It would be nice to create it, so that work (the hats in Christmas, this of the unicoins, etc) could be better honored. Something like what Google does with [the doodles](http://www.google.com/doodles/finder/2014/All%20doodles).

Comment: please, downvoters, leave a comment. I don't know if the question is stupid, is unclear, it is not useful, or if i just redacted it awfully.

Comment: Winterbash? How did you end up on that tag?

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta); the downvoters probably just don't miss the unicorns.

Comment: As i said, im talking about that stuff like the unicorns of yesterday, the hats in Christmas, etc. That's why i used the winterbash tag.

Comment: @DourHighArch thanks, my Self-esteem is now in a better state

Comment: The Winterbash pages live on: [Winterbash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com) - Is there something else you wanted from that?

Comment: Did I miss out on the free bacon?

Comment: @animuson that one is a valuable contribution!. I was thinking about a kind of gallery or archive with all the heterogeneous stuff

Comment: Funny the negative reaction this is getting.  Gotta love the meta audience - makes grumpy cat look happy :)

Comment: @AdamRackis thanks for your support! :) this is my first request and im afraid of trying it again! :)

Comment: Eh - downvotes on Meta really [don't hurt you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118965/155403) :)

Comment: @AdamRackis haha, yes indeed! Meta is run by Stackoverflow newbies that can't answer programming questions, and can't really ask decent enough questions about programming without seeing them get closed. So they come here and fire down votes at will to do justice with their own hands. :D

Comment: @Shog9 in this question i'm not asking anything about unicons itself. This is a feature request that mentions and have to mention some old features, and makes sense actually because it is not longer April 1st. So saying that it is offtopic because it is not April 1st, hopefully could be that you voted to close to fast, and maybe it should be reopened. Besides it is in a good discussion status and receiving attention from the community. Please take a look at the nature of question and consider reopening it. Thanks!