# Please make the required deletion votes count visible in the 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

Now that [popular questions take more votes to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), and now that we can [determine how many deletion votes are required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55095/determining-how-many-deletion-votes-are-required) by hovering, I would like to ask for one further step.

In the 10k tools, we get an indication of how many deletion votes have been made, but we don't get an indication of how many are necessary for a question. I would like to not waste my time on questions which will never get deleted, and would like instead to focus my 5 votes where I can actually make a difference.

Please "promote" the information currently in the tooltip onto the 10k tools Delete page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with the next build, this tooltip will show up on the 10k tools count as well, for example:

`"5 more vote(s) needed to delete this post"`