# Delete modifier based on votes

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-delete

I couldn't find the explanation about how deletion works now (quantity of votes required based on a question votes) but [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51586/stackoverflow-glasnost-or-suspensions-for-joke-questions-closed) has a net score of -9, and it requires > 3 votes.

Wasn't that feature added for positive net votes questions (ie: make it harder to deleted highly voted posts)?

Comment: I decided to not add a delete vote to that question, since it's so epically bad it should stay preserved in the meta museum :)

Comment: @Ether, I went and upvoted that questions and the answers, hoping I could keep it from being deleted.  I've now cast the first undelete vote.

Comment: Undelete vote +2 added.

Comment: @Ether, I think your argument is you don't want to see that question deleted because your uncomfortable with losing the content... Yep, if that doesn't ironically prove the point. Censorship is something that  even a few ops must disagree with.

Comment: @Evan: I don't think "uncomfortable" is quite the right word here. :p  And what makes you think I'm an op?  I'm just an ordinary user like you, except somehow most of the content I post manages not to offend people, so my reputation stays above zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, now that I looked at the question you're referring to...

-9 is just the question score. The delete barrier is formed by the total score on ALL live posts (I imagine that already deleted posts do not count, or summat) on that question. The answers total to 60 points by themselves, so subtracting the 9 from the question and you still have 51 points, or about 2 extra votes necessary.

The original announcement is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071). Conveniently, it was the first item listed under Related Questions for this question.

Comment: oh, ok... missed that it also counted answers

Comment: I guess this goes to show that you shouldn't give a really good answer to a really bad post.

Comment: ...according to the formula, I think this will take 3 extra votes to delete.

Comment: @Jon I can't see delete requirements (but you should be able to), but I always assumed it was a floor calculation, which 51/20 would be +2. Also, I believe that the whole reason this deletion schema was established in the first place was because people were complaining about the loss of "really good answers" attached to "really bad posts".

Comment: Whoops. I didn't even think to check the tooltip. It needs 5 total delete votes.

Comment: Something that I'm just realizing though is that it is now easier to flag as spam/offensive instead of trying to delete horrible posts...

Comment: I'm definitely running out of my spam/offensive votes faster than I did before, especially since I can only cast five delete votes a day now.

Comment: how is changing your behavior from deleting, to flagging spam/offensive any less offensive to the spirit of stackoverflow than sockpuppetry