# How many votes does it take to delete a question?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)

How many votes does it take to delete a question?

Comment: Check out the [Community-maintained FAQ on deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean), as well as the [privileges page for the 10k users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools). To summarize, community deletion requires at least 3 votes, [higher numbers based on the popularity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071).

Comment: Actually the last one was the one I was looking for. I saw this question with 11 votes to close it and still remained opened. I'm adding your comment as the answer. If you happen to add it your self I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

*I'm rewriting here [Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) comment, for that's the answer I was looking for*

> Check out the [Community-maintained FAQ on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean), as well as the [privileges page for the 10k users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools). To summarize, community deletion requires at least 3 votes, **[higher numbers based on the popularity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)**.

<sub>**Used under [CC-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) with [attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) to: [Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70886) on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)**</sub>

Comment: That's plagiarism!

Comment: Not anymore, I have properly attributed to Grace Note. :) Also, I ask him to add it as answer and I would mark it as accepted.

Comment: That's plagiarism!

Comment: That's plagiarism!

Comment: If you saw it was a dupe why even post an answer that adds nothing new?

Comment: It is not plagiarism since I'm using CC-wiki content :) Anyway, I've got my answer, even when it was in a form of a comment. I didn't found the answer via the search box, and that's why I created this, if someone happen to have the same question ( and like me can't find the right answer ) I hope this one would help. I'm ok with the closing status, because it is indeed duplicated.

Comment: cc-wiki doesn't mean public domain in this case, Judith

Comment: I didn't thought you were so sensitive in this regard. I didn't meant to steal his answer, just want to put it  where it belongs.

Comment: That's plagiarism! At least that's what I think. Yup, that's my 100% original thought on this topic.