# Delete votes counting mismatch

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

In the Tools -> Delete tab

[image]

While in the Post itself

[image]

Perhaps only one digit displayed in the first??

Comment: I'm sort of curious how it got 20 delete votes without getting deleted.

Comment: @Gabe It's [harder to delete popular questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071); that post will require 31 votes

Comment: @Michael: It looks like it has almost 580 votes. Hopefully it will be migrated to someplace like Codegolf.SE before it gets the 30 votes needed to delete.

Comment: @Gabe only if a diamond does it. You could flag and suggest.

Comment: @Rosinante They might make an exception for something close to deletion, but it's rare to migrate to betas, and it's rare to migrate old posts

Comment: Yeah, I said "hopefully it will be" because I figured that we'd have to wait for CG.SE to get out of beta (if ever), then hope that it's considered on-topic, then hope that they're willing to migrate a post that old.

Comment: @Michael: Does a post with 30 delete votes show all 30 voters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264/what-is-the-most-beautiful-code-you-have-ever-seen-or-written shows only 3 delete voters but requires 14 undelete votes apparently.

Comment: @Gabe Yes. The change to require more votes for popular questions was in May 2010; that post was deleted Feb 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default filter on the delete list is 2 days:

[image: Screenshot of the filters]

So the post has 20 delete votes total, but only 2 in the last two days. It actually only has 2 in the last 30 days, so widening the filter that far won't help, but the counts of other posts can change (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927230/for-statement-in-c has 18 delete votes, all in the last month but only 1 recently, so it says "1" on the 2d/7d/14d views, but 18 on the 30d -- 17 were between 15 and 30 days ago)

Comment: Seems you are right, but the number is misleading. I understand it _may_ be the right one for the "Recent votes" column, but of course NOT for the "Most Votes" one.

Comment: So there is no way from the 10K tools to get a real ranking of the  questions with most delete votes ...