# Votes Needed to Delete

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes)

How many votes do you need to delete a question?

I've seen a question with 6 delete votes still exist, but I've also seen a question get deleted upon getting 3 delete votes. What's the rule?