# What happened to my bounty on this closed question?

Tags: support, questions, bounties, closed-questions

It seems that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683117/alternative-to-annoying-captcha-in-forms-how-to-smell-the-difference-between-a-h) was closed as not constructive.

While I could argue on the "not constructive" part, especially because it was already protected and made a CW, I'd be especially interested on what happened to my earned bounty.

I checked the reputation recalc page and it is gone.
I am a little bit confused because I thought [bounty questions cannot be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067).

Comment: Moderators are not bound by mortal rules. *cue evil laugh*

Comment: In all seriousness, that question had a *lot* of problems, was was deleted (not just closed). Good question about what happens to bounties in that situation.

Comment: Okay, understood. Also I see that the question had problems especially if I read the moderator comment @hammar posted. I just think it is a bit unfair that the OP who asked a bad question get's the bounty refunded while the people who try to answer have nothing at the end. However, c'est la vie ;)

Comment: Very [Related Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103258/what-is-wrong-with-this-question-about-preventing-spam) (and ultimate cause of the deletion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of addendums: Bounty questions cannot be closed while the bounty period is active, except by a moderator.  Even then, a moderator has to refund the bounty first, then close the question.

You lost any bounty that you *had* earned on that question when it was deleted, along with any other reputation you had gained for upvoted answers on it.

Comment: Did the OP also get refunded already awarded bounties?

Comment: @Paŭlo: Good question.  I don't know if that gets refunded or if it's just lost like all the other points.

Answer (score 4):

This comment was left by a moderator before closing it (only visible for users with more than 10k rep):

> This post has been protected from closure numerous times by bounties, and received a number of moderator flags. Since it's already gotten 33 answers, I'm going to refund the bounty and close.

Comment: Refunded means the OP gets the bounty back while the person who earned the bounty gets nothing after recalc, correct?