# Is serial downvoting across multiple SE sites detected automatically?

Tags: feature-request, support, serial-voting

I have recently been downvoted on three different SE sites in a short period of time. All of the posts had high visibility on my profile (my top answers/questions or my recent ones).

It's probably just a coincidence, but it made me wonder whether the serial downvoting detection mechanism takes multiple sites into consideration.

I read the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), but this specific issue doesn't seem to be mentioned.

In case it does not, then I think it needs to be detected and removed. It's fairly easy to target a user active on multiple sites and get away with it- it shouldn't be.

Comment: I doubt it does.

Comment: Doing it would require cooperation between all SE sites, which I do not think takes place (for now).

Comment: @FredericHamidi accounts are linked across multiple sites though, so I believe users activities can be tracked.

Comment: @Gabriele, serial voting detection would require tracking both the sources and the targets of the votes across multiple sites, which is exponentially more costly than tracking a single user.

Comment: @FredericHamidi yes I agree on that.

Comment: The impact of serial downvoting across sites is less than the impact of serial downvoting on one site. If the serial voting isn't enough to trigger on each site, you're only losing 2-6 rep. Also, the perpetrator must have at least 125 rep on all of these sites. While I agree that this would be a _nice_ feature, I don't think it's a terribly _necessary_ one.

Comment: Rep is not necessarily the main concern, @Emrakul. Revenge downvotes can distort a post's score unreasonably.

Comment: @Josh I guess I just don't think that's a significant problem.

Comment: You're right, @Emrakul, it's probably not significant enough to do cross-site detection. It's [just annoying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194290/).