# Can someone provide more details about deleting?

Tags: discussion

In help center, I find [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

> However, the number of delete votes required scales to the number of votes on the question and all its answers.

Can someone provide more details about deleting mechanism? I am still a little confused.

Comment: For the popularity ratio specifically see [Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes) For the rest see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks, this totally solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

By [Jarrod Dixon♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon)'s answer in [Should delete votes be limited like close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071)?

> popular questions require more deletion votes to be deleted, at a ratio of 20:1 - a question's popularity is defined by the sum of its score plus all its answers' scores. For example, a question with score 20 will require 4 deletion votes (3 base votes + 1 popularity vote).