# Mistake in the description of Access To Moderator Tools privilege

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, help-center, wording

I think I have found a small mistake in [the description of the 10k moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). (privilege wiki?)

It says that it takes 3 votes to undelete a question:

> However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. **Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted**.

However, I just saw a question on Math.SE which was not undeleted despite having 3 undelete votes. However I also noticed it took 4 votes to delete the question.

So I think the description should be updated to say: The number of undelete votes is required is at least 3, but more if it is high-voted or if it has high-voted answers.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it would not be correct to say "as it took delete votes". The required number of undelete votes is determined by the [same formula](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071) as the number of delete votes. This may give a different result if some votes are invalidated due to a user deleted.

Comment: To make it consistent with the previous paragraphs, I would change it to "It takes 3 votes, minimum, to undelete a deleted question"