# How could a question require 18 people to be finally deleted?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, stack-exchange-history

Digging a little bit in the Data SE, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/871/revisions) old post. In 2011-11-18, it required 18 people to be finally deleted. At least, there are so many voters in the corresponding PostHistory record (id 18268039).

[image: Post deleted by 18 people]

How was it possible?

P.s. it wasn't alone, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1711/revisions) has 15 delete votes on 2012-02-21.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the total delete votes needed scale [based on score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/158100).

Doing a quick history score calculation for that question just before it was deleted gives me [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676137):

```
up  |  down | score | est. voters needed |
-----------------------------------------
401 |   8   | 393   |   19              |
```

That roughly matches the 18 voters you've found.

The number of delete votes needed today is capped at 10 but back then there was no limit.

Comment: Of course, according to the current revision of the source, "The maximum number of delete votes needed will not exceed 10." [The revision of that answer at the time of the specific post's deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/51071/2) doesn't mention this ceiling.