# Should moderators be allowed to delete accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

Moderators have too much power! They can even delete accepted answers!

See here: [Is there a Stack Exchange site for Law Questions? If not, why not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-overflow-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not) (10k users will see the deleted answer)

What happens there? The OP is not 10k so he won't see it, he won't be able to accept an answer, and he won't know why -- he will probably cry and leave us... or post a meta question reporting a bug. I don't know what's worse.

Should deleting an answer that's accepted auto-unaccept it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Where do people keep getting the idea that users lose the ability to accept an answer once the answer gets deleted?

If you try to accept a new answer to a question, it *automatically* unaccepts the previously accepted answer. You have never had to manually unaccept an answer in order to accept a new one. The only time this would've had any problem is for bounty questions during the period of time when bounties locked the acceptance, but that no longer applies anymore.

Comment: Do'h... you're right of course. What if there is a problem automatically unaccepting the deleted answer? (Trying to salvage my bug report)

Comment: Your bug report is salvaged by the fact that people *keep* having this concern - they've just only expressed it in comments or chat. There hasn't been a problem with unaccepting a deleted answer that I've seen; any scenario in which there *would* be a problem would be a pretty legitimate bug report, I would imagine.