# Allow moderators to mark flagged question as answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, moderator-tools, flags

The scenario is a user (often new user) posts a question on the site, some person(s) take the time to write a solution to the problem, the OP leaves a comment thanking the answer poster for solving their problem and moves on without ever accepting the answer. Often not revisiting the site for many months. It can be really annoying to not be rewarded for our efforts contributing to the community, and is accepted as 'just a fact of life on SO', but should it?

We vote to close questions and can flag questions for attention by moderators, so can a flag be used in the same way to alert moderators to an answer that *'should be accepted'*. This would only be in the case where there are no other accepted answers and the OP has left a comment along the lines of *'thanks this worked perfectly for me'*, etc. Not being awarded the rep points when someone has left a comment declaring an answer as the one that worked for them is quite frustrating.

Please note that I am not suggesting moderators be asked to judge the quality of an answer such as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111529/212773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.

Accepting an answer is the privilege of the question author. It basically means "I have tested this answer, and it solved the problem for me."

It doesn't make it the most correct answer, it doesn't make it the best one. It's just the one that worked for *one person*, the guy who asked the question.

If the question author doesn't accept an answer, it's his call. If your answer was really *that* good, you'll get upvotes for it.

True, it might get a bit annoying sometimes, knowing that your answer is correct, and that it's never going to be accepted. But trust me, if you put your heart into it, you'll get to the higher reputation "league" even without those few accepts.

Comment: I followed the link on the duplicate and much like the question that was posted there I find it incredibly frustrating to have stated a problem and have people instantly downvote without thoroughly reading what I am suggesting. I specifically said in the case where there are no accepted answers and the OP has left a comment thanking an answerer for solving their problem. It is not the case of trying to ensure your answer is *the most correct answer*. Perhaps I should explain myself better, or raise this as a fr for reivew to complement first post, late post, etc to take burden from mods

Comment: @SimonO101: When I see a user who is potentially unaware of that ability, I often ask him in politely in a comment to accept the answer (and instructing him on how to do so). Also, how are you offloading work from mods? You're suggesting to give them *another* responsibility, accepting flagged answers.

Comment: @SimonO101 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Bart +1 thank you for helpful info - first post here. I was duly concerned.