# Any recourse for automatically deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Regarding an unloved question of mine here:

[Tuple unpacking combined with ipython shell escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551092/tuple-unpacking-combined-with-ipython-shell-escape)

It had a drive-by downvote for some time, not sure why (no comment left).  So, it was deleted by automated system recently - since it's unanswered, more than 30 days old and with negative score.  I am not against the idea of automated cleanups, but I don't think this is a badly written question and I'm still interested in any possible future answers.

I can not vote to undelete the question, there is error dialog "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted".  Is there any way to appeal for reopening in those cases where Community♦ account may have been overzealous?  If not, would it be poor form to copy-paste and ask the same question again?

Comment: Regards to your last sentence 'If not, would it be poor form to copy-paste and ask the same question again?'... I think this is a risk of an automatic question ban. This goes same for asking questions then deleting them then re-asking them.

Comment: Given the OP's contributions that seems unlikely @535441434B. But you could just flag the deleted answer for moderator attention and explain the situation wim. (Though I guess they will pick it up here now as well)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Should questions removed automatically for inactivity really be non-undeletable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167500/). (It's about 0-score 1-year deletions, though.)

Comment: Are you able to flag it? Anyways, undeleted.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems strange that the auto-deleted questions can't be voted for undeleting, I would have thought that would be one of the most important use cases for undelete votes.

Comment: It's because [moderator delete votes are not counteractable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86710/allow-community-votes-to-undelete-q-a-that-a-moderator-has-deleted), @wim, and the Community bot counts as a mod. Definitely should be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the specific case has been addressed already, so this answer is about the general issue.

Because the auto-deletions are done by the Community user, high-rep users can't vote to undelete.  That means you'll need to convince a moderator to undelete the question.  I've seen all of the following work:

- Bring it up on your site's meta for discussion.
- Bring it up in chat.
- Flag it for moderator review; use the custom flag and explain why it should be undeleted.

Don't just repost the question; it's better to get the original one restored than to create a duplicate.

Comment: feature-request: allow undelete votes for those questions deleted by automated clean-up.

Comment: @wim I totally agree with your feature request, but hardly anyone will notice it in a comment. If you don't want to create another post tagged feature-request, you can retag this question and edit your request in.

Comment: @wim, see [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86710/162102).

Comment: Although related, that is a different request  - it is about reversing deletions by human beings trusted with the mod status. (I would not support that one). @wim, your request is not a duplicate of the other one, and is much more reasonable (and has a greater chance of being implemented).

Comment: @127.0.9.6 oh yes, you're right.  If the more-specific one about the community overriding Community isn't already asked, it should be.

Comment: @127.0.9.6, note that the current state is a side effect of a fix for a more specific problem: [a post's owner was formerly able to single-handedly undelete when others had voted for  deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/). See ["Background" in Shog's answer to "Why can I vote to reopen a deleted question?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190443/why-can-i-vote-to-reopen-a-deleted-question/222671#222671)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks for the link. It's also a side effect of another change: attributing auto-deletions to Community bot, [which wasn't always the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167502/). Unintended effects galore.

Comment: OK I added a proper feature-request, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224804/162650)