# Allow undelete votes on posts deleted by automated clean-up

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, community-user, vote-to-undelete

If a post is deleted by automated system, user can not vote to undelete because the deletion is made by the "moderator" **Community ♦**.

Users should be able to cast undelete votes in this case, rather than flagging or bringing noise to meta about it.

([background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224665/162650))

Comment: Why? If Community ♦ has stepped in, chances are the question wasn't going anywhere for quite some time. At this point, if it's any good it should be re-asked, not undeleted.

Comment: @Yannis that is not how the mods handled this case...

Comment: @rene So? Does that happen often enough to justify the feature?

Comment: @Yannis I agree it is an edge case so this becomes status-planned within the 6-8 years timeframe. I don't agree with your comment with regard to how this case should be handled in the mean time.