# Given interest in a question, how can you prevent its deletion due to one unexplained downvote?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, closed-questions

Many of my questions have been downvoted only once, with no comments or explanations tendered by the downvoter, and then automatically closed and deleted. It is inefficient and onerous afterwards to request reopenings. It seems unfair that one unexplained downvote can cause such trouble to questions that other members have deemed helpful and interesting. For example:

1. The 1 upvote of 1 comment and further comments imply at least two users interested in [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/266033/50720), which is exactly the same as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215333/50720) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/217321/50720) but only asks about 'yet' instead of 'just'.

2.  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/266387/50720 also generated some helpful comments and discussion.

To minimise this post's length, I have not replicated the deleted questions referenced above, but please advise if I should.

Comment: The downvote is only one expression that your question have problems. Getting closed and deleted is just a consequence of having those problems. We are not required to explain our votes, rest assured that most vote technically, not emotionally.

Comment: Forgive me my ignorance, but I've never seen any mechanism to automatically close any question. Can you clarify that?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Nothing to forgive. I believe that one downvote to a question with no upvoted answers, causes the closure of the question after 30 days?

Comment: @LePressentiment: It's [deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), but it's not closed first.

Comment: The lack of upvotes above 0 meant there was no interest in the question

Comment: @Random `The lack of upvotes above 0` does not imply that; see the comments that express the interest.

Comment: But they didn't think it was interesting enough to give an upvote on the question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224665/any-recourse-for-automatically-deleted-questions

Answer (score 10):

The line between gaggling and actual interest in the question is in how many of the users of the site are willing to either upvote the question, or answer the question at all.

Swarming comments is one sign of a kind of interest, but those are like Groupon users. They swoop in to make use of the comments for their own amusement and then leave when done, without any of them even upvoting the question above zero.

You can prevent your question from the [30-day negative scored auto-deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) by having the question sit at or above zero.

And that requires generating the kind of interest that is more than users leaving "that looks like an interesting question" comments and having them actually upvote it.

If nobody is upvoting, it's not the type of question they want to see stay on the site.